# Error while compiling kernel: missing double arithmetic?

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am compiling an android kernel with android toolchain. 
Inside a driver, I need to use double arithmetic, but when I compile i get lots of error, one for each time i use double type. 
For instance i get: which is int to double cast

```
/home/vektor/nckernel/customer/drivers/misc/adc_js.c:288: undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
```

To compile kernel i use this command:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/...-eabi- -j12 uImage
```

And in my Makefile i explicitly linked with `-L/path/to/libgcc.a` the gcc library to ld and gcc.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you link against `libgcc`? If yes, post your build scripts.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis would you kindly tell me how to do it? I'm still a beginner. I think this might be the problem.

Comment: I've posted a possible workaround, but to figure this out you need to provide your build script. Also, which NDK version are you using?

Comment: I commented you with the command i use to compile my kernel, plus I'm using the arm-2010q1 toolchain to compile it. With int type only it compiles flawlessly, but i need to calculate a line's slope so i need floating point

Comment: @Vektor88 Hey.. where are you using double type? In driver?? Check whether kernel supports FPU. I remember kernel does not support whole FPU functionalities.

Comment: @zair I have other files using doubles and floats so i assume my kernel supports them. However i solved my specific problem by using an algorhitm that does not use doubles and floats (bresenham line draw algorhitm)

Comment: @Vektor88: I just wanted to refresh myself about FPU support in kernel. So can you please tell me where were you using float before.. Was that in driver code??

Comment: @zair Some .c files in /drivers/usb/ use them for instance

Answer (score 2):

You may not be linking against `libgcc` for some reason. Until you figure out why, you can work around the problem by adding the following to your `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := $(call link-whole-archives, $(call host-path, $(TARGET_LIBGCC)))
```

Comment: I don't have any `Android.mk` file, it's just the kernel folder. To compile it i type on terminal `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/...-eabi- -j12 uImage` adding `-lgcc` does not solve my problem.